# Zimbra ZCS 7.2.1 MTA Deferring e-mail

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, zimbra

Zimbra 7.1.2 and the MTA seems to be deferring e-mail when it is received.

```
Oct  1 09:35:42 www postfix/error[16614]: 5FB8C1A803EE: to=<xxx@xxx.xx>,
relay=none, delay=0.15, delays=0.08/0.01/0/0.06, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery 
temporarily suspended: connect to thedigiologygroup.org[75.149.56.27]:7025: Connection
timed out)
```

I can telnet to both 25 and 7025.

I do get a

```
$ telnet thedigiologygroup.org 25
Trying 75.149.56.27...
Connected to thedigiologygroup.org.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 thedigiologygroup.org ESMTP Postfix

500 5.5.2 Error: bad syntax

500 5.5.2 Error: bad syntax`
```

I dont see email in the inbox obviously and I am not sure how to troubleshoot what is going on.

Nothing DNS has changed.

This box has been running for a year

Zimbra was removed and re-installed after trying to upgrade to ZCS-8 with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

try disabling DNS lookups on global MTA setting and server MTA setting. also check this article out. worked for me I'm also on 7.2.1

http://wiki.zimbra.com/index.php?title=Incoming_Mail_Problems